# Why is my bogo sort not running, Whats the error?

Tags: java

It doesn't output anything even after 2 numbers.
It is a Bogo sort program I am doing for improving skill but in blue J it seems to get stuck after Input so what's the issue here?
I tried to store random numbers in array b[] and check if that number is not repeated and then used that index to store a number.

````
package practice;
import java.util.*;
class bogosort
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the length to Sort");
        System.out.println("Caution this sorting could take hours if used more than 4 Numbers");
        int n;
        n=sc.nextInt();
        int a[]=new int[n],b[]=new int[n],i,j,f=0,p=0,k=0;
        System.out.println("Enter the numbers");
        for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
             a[i]=sc.nextInt();
             b[i]=-1;
        }
        while (p==0)
        {
            for (i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                b[i]=(int)Math.random()*10;
                for (j=0;j<n;j++)
                {
                    if (b[i]==b[j] && i!=j)
                    {
                        i--;
                        f=1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (f==1)
                {
                    f=0;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                a[i]=a[b[i]];
            }
            k++;
            for (i=0;i<n-1;i++)
            {
                if (a[i]>a[i+1])
                {
                    p=0;
                    break;
                }
                else
                p=1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sorted Array");
        for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("It took " + k + "turns");
    }
}```
````

Comment: this code is not generating a permutation of the input values; it is apparently overwriting some values and repeating others

Comment: Run it through a debugger to see why.

Comment: It is likely that this problem can be solved by doing basic debugging. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**  If the issue persists, please edit the question and add the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(int)Math.random()*10;` is always `0` and not a value in the interval [0, n-1].
Therefore, your sorting did not get started.

The increment of `k` was just outside the loop it should be in.

You also need not to check for equality in order to identify which elements to switch.

```
package practice;
import java.util.*;
class bogosort
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Caution this sorting could take hours if used more than 4 Numbers");
        System.out.print("Enter the length to Sort: ");
        int n;
        n=sc.nextInt();
        int a[]=new int[n],b[]=new int[n],i,j,f=0,p=0,k=0;
        for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the number " + (i+1) + ": ");
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();
            b[i]=-1;
        }
        while (p==0)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                b[i]= rand.nextInt(n);// (int)Math.random()*10;
                System.out.println("i: " + i + " b[" + i + "]: " + b[i]);
                for (j=0;j<n;j++)
                {
                    if (b[i]<b[j] && i!=j) // do check for equality here
                    {
                         // already in correct order
                        i--;
                        f=1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (f==1)
                {
                    f=0;
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("swap element at " + i + " with element at " + b[i]);
                    // swap elements
                    int tmp = a[i];
                    a[i]=a[b[i]];
                    a[b[i]] = tmp;
                }
                k++;
            }
            p=1;
            for (i=0;i<n-1;i++)
            {
                if (a[i]>a[i+1])
                {
                    // not sorted yet
                    p=0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sorted Array");
        for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("It took " + k + " turns");
    }
}
```

```
$ java bogosort.java
Caution this sorting could take hours if used more than 4 Numbers
Enter the length to Sort: 3
Enter the number 1: 3
Enter the number 2: 2
Enter the number 3: 1
i: 0 b[0]: 0
swap element at 0 with element at 0
i: 1 b[1]: 0
swap element at 1 with element at 0
i: 2 b[2]: 2
swap element at 2 with element at 2
i: 0 b[0]: 0
i: 0 b[0]: 1
i: 0 b[0]: 1
i: 0 b[0]: 2
swap element at 0 with element at 2
i: 1 b[1]: 2
swap element at 1 with element at 2
i: 2 b[2]: 0
i: 2 b[2]: 1
i: 2 b[2]: 0
i: 2 b[2]: 2
swap element at 2 with element at 2
Sorted Array
1
2
3
It took 6 turns
$
```